# How do I pull all results form a table based on another tables many to one relationship?

Tags: sql

## Setup

Sorry for the poorly phrased question. I'm not sure how to phrase it better. Feel free to try your hand at it if you are more versed in sql phrasing.

I have 3 related tables.

Person => person_id, name, etc
Cases => case_id, person_id, incedent_date, etc
Files => file_id, case_id, file_path, etc

## Problem

For a given case_id I want to pull all file_id's for the same person.

Requirements:

1. 1 query.
2. without duplicates.
3. without using UNIQUE/DISTINCT flag.
4. without changing table structure.

e.g. Bob has 2 cases, auto and house.
He has 10 files on each case.
I have the case_id for auto.
I want the files for both auto and house (20 files).

## My attempt

This returns all files for all cases.

```
SELECT 
  f.file_id AS id
FROM files f 
LEFT JOIN Cases c1 ON f.case_id = c1.case_id
LEFT JOIN Cases c2 ON f.case_id = c2.case_id 
WHERE (f.case_id = 3566 OR c1.person_id = c2.person_id)
  AND f.active = 1
ORDER BY f.upload_date ASC
```

This returns files for only given case:

```
SELECT 
  f.file_id AS id
FROM files f 
LEFT JOIN Cases c1 ON f.case_id = c1.case_id
LEFT JOIN Cases c2 ON f.case_id = c2.case_id 
WHERE (f.case_id = 3566 OR (c1.case_id = 3566 AND c1.person_id = c2.person_id)
  AND f.active = 1
ORDER BY f.upload_date ASC
```

This returns duplicate values and seems to pull only the given case:

```
SELECT 
  f.file_id AS id
FROM files f 
LEFT JOIN Cases c1 ON f.case_id = c1.case_id
LEFT JOIN Cases c2 ON c1.person_id = c2.person_id 
WHERE f.case_id = 3566
  AND f.active = 1
ORDER BY f.upload_date ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you want.

```
Create table #Person (person_id int, name varchar(10))
Insert into #Person values (1,'Ajay')
Insert into #Person values (2,'Vijay')

Create table #Cases (case_id int, person_id int)
Insert into #Cases values (1,1)
Insert into #Cases values (2,1)
Insert into #Cases values (3,1)
Insert into #Cases values (4,2)

Create  table #Files (file_id int, case_id int)
Insert into #Files values (1,1)
Insert into #Files values (2,1)
Insert into #Files values (3,1)
Insert into #Files values (4,2)
Insert into #Files values (5,4)

SELECT 
f.file_id AS id
FROM #files f 
LEFT JOIN #Cases c1 ON f.case_id = c1.case_id
LEFT JOIN #Cases c2 ON c1.person_id = c2.person_id and c2.case_id = 2
where c2.case_id is not null

--OR

SELECT *,
f.file_id AS id
FROM #files f 
LEFT JOIN #Cases c1 ON f.case_id = c1.case_id
INNER JOIN #Cases c2 ON c1.person_id = c2.person_id and c2.case_id = 2
```

Comment: Wow this seems to work. I was starting to believe what I was asking was not possible.